# Options not working | react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Options (link, Unlink, Embedded, Image, History and Emoji) are not working!

I had error when I installed react-draft-wysiwyg first time, now some of the options are not working, I Installed it with --force and it gives me this error:

> npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. npm WARN
> ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm WARN Found: react@18.1.0 npm WARN
> node_modules/react npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8.0" from
> @emotion/react@11.9.0 npm WARN   node_modules/@emotion/react npm WARN
> peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1 npm
> WARN     node_modules/@emotion/styled npm WARN     4 more
> (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project) npm
> WARN   17 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
> npm WARN  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency: npm WARN peer
> react@"0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x
> || ^17.x.x" from react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm WARN
> node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg npm WARN
> react-draft-wysiwyg@"^1.14.7" from the root project npm WARN  npm WARN
> Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2 npm WARN node_modules/react
> npm WARN   peer react@"0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x ||
> ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x || ^17.x.x" from react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm
> WARN   node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg npm WARN
> react-draft-wysiwyg@"^1.14.7" from the root project npm WARN ERESOLVE
> overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.1.0 npm WARN
> node_modules/react-dom npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
> from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.84 npm WARN   node_modules/@mui/base npm
> WARN     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.84" from @mui/material@5.8.3 npm WARN
> node_modules/@mui/material npm WARN   6 more (@mui/material,
> @testing-library/react, draft-js, ...) npm WARN  npm WARN Could not
> resolve dependency: npm WARN peer react-dom@"0.13.x || 0.14.x ||
> ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x || ^17.x.x" from
> react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm WARN node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg
> npm WARN   react-draft-wysiwyg@"^1.14.7" from the root project npm
> WARN  npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@17.0.2 npm WARN
> node_modules/react-dom npm WARN   peer react-dom@"0.13.x || 0.14.x ||
> ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x || ^17.x.x" from
> react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7 npm WARN   node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg
> npm WARN     react-draft-wysiwyg@"^1.14.7" from the root project

**Libraries:**

```
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css'
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
```

**The Code:**

```
        <Editor
            placeholder="اكتب هنا ..."
            editorState={editorState}
            toolbarClassName="toolbar-demo"
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            editor-toolbarClassName="demo-editor-toolbar"
            
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            toolbar={{
                options: ['inline', 
                'blockType', 
                'list', 
                'textAlign', 
                'link', 
                'embedded', 
                'image', 
                'history', 
                'emoji'],
                link: {
                    defaultTargetOption: '_self',
                    popupClassName: 'demo-popup-custom',
                    options: ['link', 'unlink'],
                    component: undefined,
                    popupClassName: undefined,
                },
                history: { inDropdown: true },
                image: {
                    uploadEnabled: true,
                    uploadCallback: uploadImageCallBack,
                    previewImage: true,
                    inputAccept: "image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/svg",
                    alt: { present: true, mandatory: false },
                    defaultSize: {
                        height: "auto",
                        width: "auto",
                      }
                },
                emoji: {
                    //   icon: emoji,
                    //   className: undefined,
                    //   component: undefined,
                    //   popupClassName: undefined,
                       emojis: [
                         '', '',
                       ],
                     },
            }}
        />
```

Comment: I think the issue lies here:
`npm WARN Found: react@18.1.0`
...
`npm WARN Could not resolve dependency: npm WARN peer react@"0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || ^16.x.x || ^17.x.x" from react-draft-wysiwyg@1.14.7`
It seems like `react-draft-wysiwyg` doesn't support React 18 yet